# Can a black hole exist without encircling stars? Can a black hole exist without stellar dispersion of a galaxy bulge?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies

The [M–sigma (or M–σ) relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E2%80%93sigma_relation) is an empirical correlation between the stellar velocity dispersion $σ$ of a galaxy bulge and the mass $M$ of the supermassive black hole at its center.

Some references:

- K. Gebhardt et al., "A Relationship between Nuclear Black Hole Mass and Galaxy Velocity Dispersion", [2000 *ApJ* **539** L13](http://doi.org/10.1086/312840).
- M. G. Haehnelt and G. Kauffmann, "The correlation between black hole mass and bulge velocity dispersion in hierarchical galaxy formation models", [*Mon. Not. Roy. Astron. Soc.* **318** (2000) L35](https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-8711.2000.03989.x), [arXiv:astro-ph/0007369](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0007369).

Answer (score 6):

Sort of.  It depends on what you're asking exactly.

Massive Black-hole (MBH) mass and stellar velocity dispersion are two independent properties of a galaxy, which are observed to be related.  Any galaxy (or bulge) that has stars (which is required for them to exist) can have a velocity dispersion.  That being said, a MBH doesn't necessarily need to have a host-galaxy, and similarly a galaxy doesn't necessarily need to have a MBH*.

The observed $M-\sigma$ relation is usually interpreted to mean that somehow MBHs are able to effect their large-scale environments (i.e. their galaxy as a whole).  The growing consensus is that the mechanism of this interaction is via 'Feedback', e.g. [This paper by Fabian](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4424), or [this pop-sci article](http://phys.org/news/2015-03-supermassive-black-hole-star-making-gas.html).  It is **not** interpreted to mean that the stars in the galaxy's bulge are physically orbiting the BH, and the dispersion is directly caused by that orbital velocity.

*Although, statistically it looks like basically all galaxies tend to have BHs.